# Cannot redeclare class in bootstrap.php.cache

Tags: php, symfony

I upgraded to Symfony 3.2 today and get 500 error in prod environment.
This is the error in apache error log:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare class
Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\HttpKernelInterface in
/services/applications/red-secure/var/bootstrap.php.cache on line 1309
```

I have tried to clear cache and delete cache folder.
It works in dev environment.

This is my app.php:

```
$loader = require __DIR__.'/../app/autoload.php';
include_once __DIR__.'/../var/bootstrap.php.cache';

$kernel = new AppKernel('prod', false);
$kernel->loadClassCache();

$request = Request::createFromGlobals();
$response = $kernel->handle($request);
$response->send();
$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

Anyone?

UPDATE:
I think something went wrong when I updated the project to 2.8. I created a new 3.2-project and copied all the files. Everything is working now.

Comment: you can rebuild the `bootstrap.php.cache` file with a simple `composer update`

Comment: @Federkun I tried to delete it, and then rebuild, but still 500 error.

Comment: check where's the duplicate. go to `bootstrap.php.cache`, ctrl+f, "interface HttpKernelInterface" -> how may?

Comment: Comment out the include_once for the bootstrap file in app.php just to verify the problem lies there.  It sure seems like your bootstrap file was not rebuilt.

Comment: This has happened to me many times with entity classes. Not sure the reason but usually, clearing cache, deleting the cache directory or deleting the entities (remote dev server) and uploading again has fixed it.